# How to open ajax model popup extender just like facebook image viewer?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I want to use ajax ModelpopupExtender control in my .aspx page in visual studio 2010. When user clicks any button,It should open popup like facebook opens popup to show photos. That means pop up should get opened in such a way that it should disable the background until closed button is clicked of that popup. How to open page or panel or any other thing in that popup. Please mention clear steps. I dont have even bit of idea how to do this?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  
CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" 
Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Ajax Model PopUp Extender With MouseOver Example</title>
<link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript">

        function MouseHover() 
     {
         $find("modelPopupExtender1").show();
     }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="toolKitScriptManager1" 
                                  runat="server">
</ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>    
<p style="background-color: #9999FF; width: 95%;">

Example of using a ModalPopupExtender with with Mouse Over
<br/></p><br/>
Hover over the hyperlink 
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" 
               onmouseover="MouseHover();" 
               Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="Blue">
<b>Mouse Over Here to Open PopUp</b>
</asp:HyperLink> to open pop up

<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender runat="server" 
                   BehaviorID="modelPopupExtender1" 
                   TargetControlID="HyperLink1"
                   PopupControlID="popUpPanel" 
                   OkControlID="btnOk" 
                   BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" >
</ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel ID="popUpPanel" runat="server" 
           CssClass="confirm-dialog">
<div class="inner">
<h2>
Thanks For Visiting This Site</h2>
<div class="base">
<asp:Button ID="btnOk" runat="server" Text="Ok"/>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" 
                CssClass="close" 
OnClientClick="$find('modelPopupExtender1').hide(); return false;"/>
</div></div>
</asp:Panel>



    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"** did you notice this line this is where you define the css for the background.

I think this should work.
[Reference](http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2011/03/ajax-modalpopupextender-example-aspnet.html)